# How To Pass Data From Database Apps To Theme App Extensions Without Metafield?

Tags: node.js, shopify, backend, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I am trying to figure out how to pass data between database apps to theme app extensions. In backend, Merchant can create, edit and delete data and it will update database. I also try using Metafield in Product, but when I want to assign metafield to multiple products, it take too much time to save metafield in every product.

How can I pass data from Database to Theme App Extension to update latest data to display on Online Store?

My theme app extension as below:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ4CD.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ8De.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. One, the obvious one, is using Liquid, and rendering your custom data using Liquid, which implies, Metafields. You say that takes too much time, but the reality is, that is by far the best way.

Your second option is to use an App Proxy. It is slower, and prone to network problems obviously, but it does allow your extension to access data from the App's database.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I dont want to use App Proxy and Metafields. I want belike https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ8De.png